# Pymongo update not updating, and with no errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have some simple code to mark an error as solved

```py
doc = self.data.find_one({"id": int(errid)})
print(doc)
updt = self.data.update_one(filter={"id": errid}, update={"$set": {"fixed": True}})
doc = self.data.find_one({"id": int(errid)})
print(f"{doc}\n\n{str(updt.upserted_id)}\n\n{updt.acknowledged}")
print(f"Successfully fixed error {errid}")
```

(yes, all the vars are defined)

The first time I print `doc`, I get

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fc048878dc1679d5d880f6b'), 'id': 12, 'command': 'errortest', 'fulltb': 'https://hastebin.com/otepiqihim', 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 0, 29, 59, 708000), 'fixed': False}
```

The second time, I get the exact same result. The update is acknowledged, (`updt.acknowleged`) but the ID is `None` (`updt.upserted_id`)

I don't get any errors either. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If your errid is a string, you're casting it to an int in all places **except** om the update command

```
updt = self.data.update_one(filter={"id": errid}, update={"$set": {"fixed": True}})
```

should be:

```
updt = self.data.update_one(filter={"id": int(errid)}, update={"$set": {"fixed": True}})
```